# I can't select my second paragraph inside my parent class

Tags: html, css

I have the following html

```
  <div class="parentt">
        <p>p 1</p>
        <p>p 2</p>
        <p>p 3</p>
    </div>
```

so if i want to style the second p inside my parentt class i will do

```
.parentt > p:nth-child(2) {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

but when my html is mixed

```
<div class="parentt">
        <p>p 1</p>
        <h2>sdsd</h2>
        <p>p 2</p>
        <p>p 3</p>
    </div>
```

and i put inside `h2` tag, my css is not working any more because now nth-child 2 is not paragraph but it is h2.

How can i dynamically first select all p inside and after that to select the second p inside?

Because sometimes the second p inside the `parrent` can appear on nth-child number 8 for example.
I can't change every time my css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such cases you could use `nth-of-type` instead of `nth-child`

```css
.parentt > p:nth-of-type(2) {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentt">
        <p>p 1</p>
        <h2>sdsd</h2>
        <p>p 2</p>
        <p>p 3</p>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `nth-of-type`

```
.parentt > p:nth-of-type(2) {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:nth-of-type()` pseudo selector. You can read more [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-of-type/)

```css
.parentt p:nth-of-type(2) {
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentt">
  <p>p 1</p>
  <h2>sdsd</h2>
  <p>p 2</p>
  <p>p 3</p>
</div>
```